# How to persist aggregates with repositories?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, persistence, aggregateroot

I am trying to learn some concepts about DDD and the part of persisting Aggregates is confusing me a bit. I have read various answers on the topic on SO but none of them seem to answer my question.

Let's say I have an Aggregate root of Product. Now I do not want to inject the **ProductRepository** that will persist this aggregate root in the constructor of the **Product** class itself. Imagine me writting code like

```
var prod = new Product(Factory.CreateProductRepository(), name, costprice);
```

in the UI layer. If I do not want to inject my repository via dependency injection in the Aggregate Root, then the question is where should this code go? Should I create a class only for persisting this AR? Can anyone suggest what is the correct & recommended approach to solve this issue?

My concern is not which ORM to use or how to make this AR ORM friendly or easy to persist, my question is around the right use of repositories or any persistence class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Application Services

You are right, the domain layer should know nothing about persistence. So injecting the repository into `Product` is indeed a bad idea.

The DDD concept you are looking for is called **Application Service**. An application service is **not** part of the domain layer, but lives in the service layer (sometimes called application layer). Application services represent a *use case* (as opposed to a domain concept) and have the following responsibilities:

- Perform input validation
- Enforce access control
- **Perform transaction control**

The last point means that an application service will query a repository for an aggregate of a specific type (e.g. by ID), modify it by using one of its methods, and then pass it back to the repository for updating the DB.

### Repository Ganularity

Concerning your second question

> Should I create a class only for persisting this AR?

Yes, creating one repository per aggregate is a common approach. Often, standard repository operations like `getById()`, `update()`, `delete()`, etc. are extracted into a reusable class (either a base class or by aggregation).

You can also create additional repositories for non-domain information, e.g. statistical data. In these cases, make sure that you don't accidentally miss a domain concept, however.

Comment: In short, think: Factory.CreateProductRepository()->persist(product)

Comment: Wonderful answer! Thanks :)

Comment: I like your idea and will think about how it could be incorporated further. What worries me is that the system will need a middle layer to communicate with the BL in that case. A side note about the answer: I have read everywhere that generic repositories are discouraged especially in DDD and I can see the reason behind it is to maintain the intent of the change in relation to the business.